# How can I add a whole *.reg to the windows registry file using debian/ubuntu?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, debian, windows-registry

I can edit the windows 7 registry from a debian/ubuntu using chntpw.

How can I add a whole *.reg file using debian/ubuntu?
It is simply a double click in Windows but in unix?

Comment: Not sure if you've seen this or it's at all helpful? [link](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/regedit.txt)

Comment: have you actually tried googling for `regedit+linux`? It brings so many results it's ridiculous.